# Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions complete documentation?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to beanstalk, and even AWS. I've successfully deployed a Node/Express app which serves a React/Redux SPA.

I've had to hack together some post-deploy scrips as .ebextension config files, and in doing so, it seems like there is a ton of documentation missing. For example, in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html, there is a section talking about config file options like:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: "npm start"
```

I haven't been able to find anywhere that mentions other namespaces, other options in the nodejs namespace, other option setting options, etc. Ebextensions basically seems like a big black box.

Is there any complete documentation or helpful resources anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could find the general option settings here "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html" and platform specific option settings here "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html".

Also, other possible customizations via ebextensions are present in "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html". Hope this helps!